# Add SqLite to PHP5

Tags: php, ubuntu, sqlite

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit and installed the `php5` package from the repositories which brought Apache with it. Php itself works but when I try to use `new SQLiteDatabase([...])`, the error

> Fatal error:  Class 'SQLiteDatabase' not found in [...] on line [...]

is printed.

The `php.ini` in use is `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` (according to `phpinfo()` ([link to the website it prints](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9402513/phpinfo%28%29.html))). I noticed that in the `php.ini` the block

```
[sqlite]
; http://php.net/sqlite.assoc-case
;sqlite.assoc_case = 0

[sqlite3]
;sqlite3.extension_dir =
```

doesn't set an extension directory. I tried finding files called `sqlite3` on my system and putting a path to their directories in there, but it didn't work (and I restarted my machine after changing the `php.ini`).

The package `php5-sqlite3` doesn't exist for Ubuntu 14.04 but `php5-sqlite` does and I installed it before trying anything else. I then also installed the packages `sqlite3` and `sqlite`, but again: I doesn't work.

Comment: can you find information about sqlite ext in your phpinfo() ?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Do you mean `sqlite3.extension_dir`? If so: Both `Local Value` and `Master Value` are set to "no value". Otherwise: I added the website `phpinfo()` prints to my question: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9402513/phpinfo%28%29.html

Comment: have you restarted your apache server after sqlite installing?

Comment: Yes, I did. (Some more characters so I can post this comment.)

Comment: well, I have same error after trying to install.. I will testing and answer to you, when find a solution

Comment: so, first results.. as alternative, you can use PDO for working with sqlite. something like $db = new PDO("sqlite:your_db.db"); I continue to search other solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. So, according to http://stevenclark.info/wp/fatal-error-class-sqlitedatabase-not-found-in/

> As of PHP 5.4 the SQLiteDatabase class was removed to make way for
>   SQLite 3.

So, you need to use this:

```
$db=new SQLite3("db.sqlite");
```

Comment: That would've been it? Oo It works, thank you! PDO also works!